# Is different bottom tab navigation for only screen allowed on Apple Store and Google Play

Tags: android, ios, react-native, google-play, app-store

I have a client that wants the bottom tab navigation to have something similar to sub-navigation only for one screen that includes different tabs. The navigation that is on all other screens is hidden behind arrow - This arrow is also only on this screen and not on the default bottom tab navigator.

Bottom tab (sub)navigation on one screen:

[image: Representation of the sub-navigation bottom tab]

[image: Bottom tab with the default bottom tab navigator]

Default bottom tab navigator on all screens:

[image: Default bottom tab navigator on all pages]

The app will be built with React Native and they heard from a designer that this approach with sub bottom navigation is not supported by Apple Store or Google Play.

Does anyone know if this is true?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is allowed but not recommended by Google & Apple. and you will have to create a custom navigation bar to do this because it is not supported by apple or Google.